# Is there an API to retrieve the neo4j relationship details using the Go bolt driver?

Tags: go, neo4j

Using the neo4j Go bolt driver, I am able to get nodes, but not relationships from the graph db.

The `Run()` API in neo4j.transaction return type is `Result` which can give nodes, but not to the relationships?

If I try the query in the neo4j browser, it shows me the properties of the relationships, but if I send the same query programmatically, I don’t get anything. Am I missing something?

```
MATCH (:a {name: ‘foo’})-[r:bar]->() RETURN properties(r)
```

The above query works

```
{
  "X":"20",
  "Y":"40"
}
```

But the same query sent via the driver returns no error, but has nothing in it.

Answer (score 1):

There might be something wrong with your mapping code.
It should look like this:

```golang
func readCoordinates(driver neo4j.Driver) ([]Coordinates, error) {
    session := driver.NewSession(neo4j.SessionConfig{})
    defer session.Close()
    result, err := session.ReadTransaction(executeReadCoordinates)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return result.([]Coordinates), nil
}

func executeReadCoordinates(tx neo4j.Transaction) (interface{}, error) {
    records, err := tx.Run("MATCH (:A {name: 'foo'})-[r:BAR]->() RETURN properties(r)", map[string]interface{}{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var results []Coordinates
    for records.Next() {
        record := records.Record()
        if props, found := record.Get("properties(r)"); !found {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("expected properties not found")
        } else {
            properties := props.(map[string]interface{})
            coordinates := Coordinates{
                X: properties["x"].(int64),
                Y: properties["y"].(int64),
            }
            results = append(results, coordinates)
        }
    }
    return results, nil
}
```

I changed the case of the node label (convention: PascalCase), relationship type (convention: SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE) and properties (convention: snake_case).

The code assumes those properties are of type `int64` and fetches a list.
If you want a single pair of coordinates, then remove the `for` loop and use `records.Single()` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I had an issue with the type assertion. Your code was helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help. Feel free to accept the answer ;)